# Tailwind CSS :before pseudo class

Tags: reactjs, storybook, tailwind-css, emotion, css-in-js

I've now been working in circles trying to understand what is happening. I'm making a design library using storybook with Tailwind. I can't seem to get the :before pseudo class to work. No matter where I place it in the styling, then it's never rendered.

An example is that I am trying to make a component which uses react-slick, and want to style the navigation:

```
'& .slick-dots': {
  bottom: -30,
  display: 'block',
  left: 4,
  listStyle: 'none',
  margin: 0,
  padding: 0,
  position: 'absolute',
  textAlign: 'center',
  width: '100%',

  '& li': {
    cursor: 'pointer',
    display: 'inline-block',
    height: 20,
    margin: '0 5px',
    padding: 0,
    position: 'relative',
    width: 20,

     '& button': {
       border: 0,
       background: 'transparent',
       display: 'block',
       height: 20,
       width: 20,
       outline: 'none',
       lineHeight: 0,
       fontSize: 0,
       color: 'transparent',
       padding: 5,
       cursor: 'pointer',

       '&:before': {
        position: 'absolute',
        top: 0,
        left: 0,
        content: '',
        width: 20,
        height: 20,
        fontFamily: 'sans-serif',
        fontSize: 20,
        lineHeight: 20,
        textAlign: 'center',
        color: '#000000',
        opacity: 0.75,
        display: 'inline-block',
      },
    },
  },
},
```

Comment: Can you show code snipper or sandbox (jsfiddle, codepen)?

Comment: It's ok, found the problem. The :before pseudo class won't render unless there is content, but in the case of css in js, then content needs to look like this ```content: '"text"',``` and not ```content: 'text',```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found the problem. The :before pseudo class won't render unless there is content, but in the case of css in js, then content needs to look like this `content: '"text"',` and not `content: 'text',`

Answer (score 1):

Another way is to define your content in the **tailwind.config.js**

```
theme: {
    extend: {
      content: {
        'arrowNeonGreen': 'url("../src/images/icons/arrow-neon-green.svg")',
      },
      fontSize: {
...
```

You can render it using the following className. Make sure to include an **inline-block** and **width**.

```
<Link className="after:content-arrowNeonGreen after:inline-block after:w-8">Learn More</Link>
```

You can also apply a hover state like this **hover:after:content-arrowNeonGreen**

```
<Link className="hover:after:content-arrowNeonGreen after:content-arrowBlack after:inline-block after:w-8">Learn More</Link>
```

Answer (score 0):

to get the :before class to work, you have to use tailwindcss-pseudo-elements package to customize your pseudo elements. check the docs below

https://www.npmjs.com/package/tailwindcss-pseudo-elements